# How do we create a short cut for an application and pass parameters?

Tags: applications

I am trying to find out, how can I create a short cut of an application and add a parameter to the application short cut so that when it executes, it executes with that parameter. In Windows, I can right click and create a short and then go to properties and in the target area, I can add the additional parameter it has to use to run. Is it possible to do it in Mac?

Comment: Of course it's possible, although it might help to know the application and argument/parameter too.

Comment: I am trying to launch Stablecoin-qt app with -server parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps aren't really designed on OSX like Windows apps.

The easiest way is to create a command file :

`open ./AppName.app --args yourArgs`